# .net Core Console application in Docker Container throws System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, console-application

i found many entries to this issue but no solution worked for me.

In short i have a .net Core 3.1 console application which i want to run in Docker. If i start the Application in Visual Studio or via the commandline all works fine (Debug and Release build).

If i put it in a Docker container, i get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
```

My Program.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace testapp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Startup.Init(out _serviceProvider);

            var ended = new ManualResetEventSlim();
            var starting = new ManualResetEventSlim();

            var dataStorage = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDataStorageService>();

            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ctx =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unloding fired");
                starting.Set();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for completion");
                ended.Wait();
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for signals");
            starting.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Received signal gracefully shutting down");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            ended.Set();
        }

    }
}
```

And my Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;

namespace testapp
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Init(out IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            Injection(out serviceProvider);
        }

        private static void Injection(out IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {

                    services.AddSingleton<IDataStorageService, DataStorageService>();


                    services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());
                }).Build();

            serviceProvider = builder.Services;

            var configService = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigService>();

            Console.WriteLine("ElasticUrl: " + configService.GetElasticEndpoint());

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File("consoleapp.log")
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configService.GetElasticEndpoint()))
                {
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    TypeName = "_doc",
                    ModifyConnectionSettings = c => c.GlobalHeaders(new NameValueCollection
                        {{"Authorization", configService.GetElasticAuthentication()}})
                })
                .CreateLogger();

            builder.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception is thrown at this line in Program.cs:

```
var dataStorage = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDataStorageService>();
```

In the Startup.cs the line `var configService = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigService>();` is working.

As i mentioned, all is running and working in visual Studio or if i launch the commandline tool within the CLI. 
Only in Docker the Exception occures.
Here is the DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ app/

ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/testapp.dll"]
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Why aren't you using the `CreateHostBuilder` method to build your host ? The docs state to use the method to create a `HostBuilder` and configure it. Also, reference to docs for calling services from `Main()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-services-from-main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jandrew
Thank you for your comment.
I could not use the method from the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-services-from-main) 1:1 as i am building a .net core console application and not an asp.net core application.

I used `ConfigureServices` instead of `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`. Works fine for me

Comment: What was your solution for problem?